# MFC C++ - How to call Init() in new dialog opened with button in Main Dialog

Tags: mfc

I use VS 2013.
I am new into MFC and I have already created Dialog box with button which opens new dialog. 
I call constructor of the new dialog in Event_button_handler and use method DoModal. It works perfectly.

But my problem appears when I want to add for example Slider Control in new dialog. I followed this tutorial: http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/tutorial_3.html
but there is no such method like OnInit(); which I used in my main dialog.

How can I handle this? Thanks

Comment: Did you try simply adding the `OnInit()` function?

Comment: Yea, but when I did it, the "cancel" button didn't wanted to work. NVM, I have accomplish that in another way. 

But now I have little trouble, I got viarable INT X in my main window, and I want to get value of this variable to be displayed in new dialog. This variable is private. 

I want in constructor of newDialog to obtain some values from MainDialog and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: The parent dialog can pass private members to child dialogs it creates.  If that's not viable for some reason, simply write a "getter" function.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `OnInit()` in this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

OnInitDialog should look like this:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    //... initialize slider
    return res;
}
```

That tutorial skips an important line `CDialog::OnInitDialog();`